# Altering a byte of the certificate hash of a signed exe

Tags: hash, byte, exe, sha1

I want to learn a little bit about the logic of the execution of a digitally signed exe file. I am trying to invert a byte of a signed exe file, more specifically the SHA1 hash (I know that this modification results in a corrupt file or signature). With [signtool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool) I am getting the following output for `chrome.exe`:

```
 Issued to: Google LLC
 Issued by: DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA
 Expires:   Wed Nov 17 13:00:00 2021
 SHA1 hash: CB7E84887F3C6015FE7EDFB4F8F36DF7DC10590E
```

Is there a tool I can use to change any byte of the SHA1 hash, save the exe and then execute it? I tried different hex editors but can't find the "SHA1 hash string".

I would like to know how Windows handles this kind of modification (execute anyway, error message etc.).